# Search in one column from one table of a MySQL database and return different column

Tags: mysql, mysql-workbench

I'm trying to search a table to find a specific string and I only want it to return one column of the row that the match was found in.

I have this

```
Select * from staff.list where Concat(name) like "%mark%";
```

But this returned the entire line and that not what I want.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Instead of `Select *` do `Select <comma separated list of columns you want>`. For example to only get the name you can do the following:

```
Select name from staff.list where Concat(name) like "%mark%";
```

Comment: Glad that it worked and welcome to Stack Overflow! In addition to accepting answers on your own questions you can also upvote any answers to reward answers that are helpful for you. I hope you will enjoy yourself here on Stack Overflow.